# How do I test a click event using Jest?

Tags: jestjs

This is not a real application, I'm just trying to learn the basics of Jest. Here I want to test a simple click event and make sure the correct callback is called when the event is fired. I set up 2 spyOn's to check if the event and then the correct callback were called.

The first 'expect' passes, so the testEvents() function is called. The second 'except' fails with the message :

> ```
> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
>
>     Expected number of calls: >= 1
>     Received number of calls:    0
> ```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. It's hard to find any info on testing vanilla JS with Jest and a few articles and other stack overflow questions I found were helpful enough to get me started but couldn't help to solve this problem.

The code:

```js
// app.js

function testEvents() {
  document.querySelector('.test1').addEventListener('click', callOnClick);
}

function callOnClick() {
  console.log('clicked');
}

module.exports = { testEvents, callOnClick };
```

```js
// app.test.js

beforeEach(() => {
  initDOM();
});


afterEach(() => {
  clearDOM();
});

describe('Event tests', () => {

  const spyClick = jest.spyOn(app, 'callOnClick');
  const spyEvent = jest.spyOn(app, 'testEvents');
  
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('Test event', () => {

    app.testEvents();
    document.querySelector('.test1').click();

    expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenCalled(); // passed
    expect(spyClick).toHaveBeenCalled(); // failed
  })

function initDOM() {
  document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div class="test1"></div>
    <div class="test2"></div>
  `;
}

function clearDOM() {
  document.body.innerHTML = ``;
}
```

Comment: where do you actually call callOnClick function? I can't see in your code. If you never call callOnClick then ofc you only have 0 calls.

Comment: @JHIH-LEI It's the callback for the event listener in the testEvents function. It's called right in the top of the original file. Then I spy on testEvents in my test file, so it should register the call of callOnClick. I think so at least, I'm still not entirely sure how mocking and spyOn in particular work.

Comment: maybe the problem is afterEach(() => {
  clearDOM();
}); can u try to delete that and move  clearDOM() into describe context's afterEach?

Answer (score 0):

```
// app.test.js

describe('Event tests', () => {

  const spyClick = jest.spyOn(app, 'callOnClick');
  const spyEvent = jest.spyOn(app, 'testEvents');

 beforeEach(() => {
  initDOM();
 });


afterEach(() => {
  clearDOM();
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});
  
  it('Test event', () => {

    app.testEvents();
    document.querySelector('.test1').click();

    expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenCalled(); // passed
    expect(spyClick).toHaveBeenCalled(); // failed
  })

function initDOM() {
  document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div class="test1"></div>
    <div class="test2"></div>
  `;
}

function clearDOM() {
  document.body.innerHTML = ``;
}
```